# How to use "Contain" in List?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have country database likes ,

```
Country
-------
England
Germany
Italy
...
```

I get this data source as ,

```
   DB.Countries.ToList();
```

What I want to do is to check new added country is already exists or not ,
just likes ,

```
if(DB.Countries.ToList().Contains(newAddedCountry))
{
 ..............
}
```

But I don't know how to convert `newAddedCountry`(string) to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Country>` .

Comment: provide table structure

Comment: Note that `ToList` should be the last statemenet since it loads the query into memory. Consider a table with millions of records, you would load all into memory before you would start filtering or ordering them. All before can be optimized by the rdbms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if(DB.Countries.Any(c => c.Country == newAddedCountry))
{
    // exists ..
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) method;

> Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

```
if( DB.Countries.Any( n => n.Country == newAddedCountry ))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
if(DB.Countries.Any(c => c.CountryName == newAddedCountry.CountryName ))
{
    // exists ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the Name of the country against your property in `Country` class. Something like:

```
if(DB.Countries.ToList().Any(r=> r.Name == newAddedCountry))
                                 ^^^^^^
                                 Field/Property name holding the Name of Country
```

if you want to compare string ignoring case then:

```
if(DB.Countries.ToList()
               .Any(r=> r.Name.Equals(newAddedCountry, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to just use a property of your `Country` class instead, like so:

```
if (db.Countries.Select(x => x.Name).ToList().Contains(countryName))
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
if (db.Countries.Any(x => x.Name == countryName))
{
    ...
}
```

which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Country` as column name:

```
if(DB.Countries.ToList().Any(c => c.Country == newAddedCountry))
{ 
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember this right, contains uses Equals method to compare instances. So you'd need to implement a Equals override method in your Countries class. And in any way - you are trying to compare String and Countries object instance, so ofcourse they don't get to be compared properly.

I'd try going for LINQ solution:

```
List<Country> countries = DB.Countries.ToList();
if (countries.Any(x => x.column == newAddedCountry)) {
    ...
}
```

or `x == newAddedCountry` if it's just a List.